# Creating URL for custom php file

Tags: wordpress

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to make a custom URL in the admin area for my plugin. I already know how to use the add_menu function, but I need to create a sub-page for the plugin which wont be listed in a menu. I can't figure out how to define a URL for this page though.

Basically I just need it to do if they view "admin.php?page=my_page" then use the function I have made which simply does an include on the .php file for the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the    ?page=my_page

if you want to add more to the url  then  use

?page=my_page&page-id

you  will directory able  to access this   in admin area no need to use extra like bloginfo something for whole url

hope this will help you

Comment: It needs to be defined in the plugin file what to do when someone goes to ?page=my_page. As of right now its not an existing page because there is no corresponding page with this URL. However I don't know how to connect this URL to an actual file.

Comment: try  this  you can get all the answer of your question  http://vikasbruce.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-short-plugin-with-short.html

Comment: No luck... :'(

`function scholarship_page3() {
 include 'scholarship_admin3.php';
}

add_shortcode('scholarship_view', 'scholarship_page3');`

Comment: include ('../../scholarship_admin3.php');  try to  rectify the path like this

Comment: The pathing is correct, as I use the same pathing on other includes for `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page`. In those 2 functions though they let you define a url slug and then a function to execute when that slug is visited.

Comment: add_menu_page('Side Gallery', 'Side Gallery','read','my-plug','',$icon_path.'/icon.png');

add_submenu_page('my-plug', 'Side Gallery', '1st Submenu', 'read', 'my-plug','my_menu_default');                   add_submenu_page('my-plug', 'Side Gallery', '2st Submenu', 'read', 'my-plug','my_menu_default2');